# PHP Strange behaviour of foreach

Tags: php

I've a code:

```
$csv = file('some.csv');

foreach($csv as $value)
{
    echo $value;
}
```

Everything is OK until the request method was POST - then the last element of an array is missing (thought it's showing properly by print_r($csv)).

What may the problem be? That's the WHOLE CODE!

Comment: Can you include the contents of your file as well?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'd say "missing line ending on last line".

Comment: What data does POST contain and how is it used?

Comment: Additional context may be helpful. Is the URL different when the script is called via GET or POST? Is 'some.csv' the real file name, or have you edited the code before posting it here? Does 'some.csv' reside in the same directory as the PHP script?

Comment: Are you sure it's the whole code? There is nothing related to POST here...

Comment: @Tim Cooper - it's some foo bar type data - simply 3 lines of some data, @ETWW-Dave - there is line ending on last line, @Abhay - POST data is not used in this case - it occurs whenever `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST';` @Felix Kling - that's because POST data is not used at all in this particular case

Comment: But you said "Everything is OK until the request method was POST"! Please make your question clearer so we can understand where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
$csv = file('some.csv');

// Loop through our array
foreach ($cvs as $line_num => $line) {
    echo $line."<br />\n";
}
```